# How hide border on embedded swf

Tags: html, css, wordpress, border

I can't hide the gray border around an embedded .sfw file. 
It is a swf inserted by Wordpress plugin, called *shortcode*. SWF is on my page [here](http://a.vinylart.pl). Can You tell me how to do it?

I edited the plugin PHP and I give `<object>` and `<embed>` the class `#swf_object`. After that I edited the CSS and I tried to hide this border but it is still there. Before that, I also tried to add `border:none;` in style.css (style of my theme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to hide the border since it can't be removed:

for `.home_display` add `overflow:hidden; height: 579px;`

and for you flash object which is inside your `.home_display` add this css:

```
left: -1px;
position: relative;
top: -1px;
```

Comment: First one is preferable, cause he use this rule with **id selector**. In the second one you have a typo: missed "r" in "border".

Comment: No, that is only there becouse i tried to change something, and you look at css the same time. I know css, and i tried to do it in that way but i can't...

Comment: @Adam are you really sure that border isn't coming from flash object itself?

Comment: I think that is problem, is any way to hide it? I can't edit .swf file, but i can try to do it, i think is a converter for swf to editable file...

Comment: @Adam yes the problem is the swf file itself, please take a look at this http://s-w.lt/flash.php here you can clearly see that there is no border applied with css since page is completely clean, as for hiding it i will try to hide it in a moment

Comment: @Linas thanks, so i know how to do it now, I thought that is something wrong with style.css